# object and nested object generate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an automated generated object

```
this.state={
 fruits = []
}
```

Here is how I generate objects and insert to `fruits`

```
const gen = (fruitname, price) => {
     this.setState({
        this.state.fruits: {...this.state.fruits, [fruitname]: price}
    })
}
```

output is

```
{apple: "$2", banana: "$4", orange: "$6"}
```

Now I need to nest types in looks like below

```
   {apple: {
        "red": "$3",
        "Cripps": "$3",
        "Honeycrisp": "$5"
    }, 
    banana: {
        "small": "$4",
        "yellow": "$5",
        "green": "$2"
    },
    ...
   }
```

I updated code to

```
 const gen = (fruitname, price, types, eachPrice) => {
         this.setState({
            this.state.fruits: {...this.state.fruits, [fruitname]: { [types]: eachPrice} }
        })
    }
```

However, I only get one object of each fruit that each time I type

{apple: {
    "red": "$3",
}, 
banana: {
    "small": "$4",
},
...
}

How to keep all ?

Comment: what determines the price for each type? Your function only accepts one price, but your output has multiple different prices for each type

Comment: so would `types` be an array like `["red", "Cripps", "Honeycrisp"]` and then `eachPrice` would also be an array which has the prices like `["$3", "$3", "$5"]`?

Comment: @NickParsons yes! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to map an array of `types` (keys) to values (`eachPrice`) in an object. If this is the case you can use `.reduce` to achieve this. Here I am reducing the `types` array to an object, where each `type` is a key and each value is its corresponding price from the `eachPrice` array.

See example below:

```js
let state = {}
const gen = (fruitname, types, eachPrice) => {
  state.fruit = {...state.fruit,
    [fruitname]: 
      types.reduce((acc, t, i) => (
        { ...acc, [t]: eachPrice[i]}
      ), {})
  }
}

gen("apple", ["red", "Cripps", "Honeycrisp"], ["$3", "$3", "$5"]);
gen("banana", ["small", "yellow", "green"], ["$4", "$5", "$2"]);
       
console.log(state.fruit);
```

Note that this function doesn't use the `price` argument as you have `eachPrice` to define the prices.

Answer (score 1):

First clone the state.

check if it is already in state, if it's there than just adjust that particular key/value and manipulate if not than create a new one.

```js
let state = {apple:{"red":"$3","Cripps":"$3","Honeycrisp":"$5"},banana:{"small":"$4","yellow":"$5","green":"$2"},}

function handleState(name,type,price){
  if(state[name]){
    let temp = {...state}
    temp[name][type] = price
    return {
      ...temp,
    }
  } else {
    return{
      ...state,
      [name]:{
        [type]: price
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(handleState('apple','red','$20'))
console.log(handleState('test','red','$20'))
```